# Google Script : HTML form navigates through the records on Spreadsheet - Not working

Tags: javascript, html, forms, google-apps-script, google-sheets

```js
function getList() {
  var ss= SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var recordSheet = ss.getSheetByName("CONTACTS");
  var getLastRow = recordSheet.getLastRow();
  return recordSheet.getRange(2,1,getLastRow - 1,6).getValues();
}

function startForm(){

var form = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Records').setTitle('Records');
SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showSidebar(form);

}

function addMenu()
{
var menu = SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu('Custom');
  menu.addItem('Dropdown Form', 'startForm');
  menu.addToUi();
}

function onOpen(e)
{
addMenu();
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
 
   <script> 
    function loadRecords(record){
    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler (function(ar)
    {
    var record = document.getElementById ("record").value;
    
    consule.log(ar);
    consule.log(record);
    
    var recordCount = 0;
    
    ar.forEach(function(item,index)
    {
    if(index == record - 1)
    {
    document.getElementById("firstname").value = item[0];
    document.getElementById("lastname").value = item[1];
    document.getElementById("street").value = item[2];
    document.getElementById("city").value = item[3];
    document.getElementById("state").value = item[4];
    document.getElementById("zip").value = item[5];
    
    }
    recordCount++;
    });
    
    console.log(recordCount);
    document.getElementById("maxRecord").value = recordCount;
   
   }).getList(); 
   
   }
   
      
  function NextRecord()
   {
   var record = document.getElementById("record").value;
   var maxRecord = document.getElementByID("maxRecord").value;
   var nextRecord = Number(record) + 1;
   if(nextRecord <== maxRecord)
   {
   document.getElementById("record").value = nextRecord;
   loadRecords();
   }
   }
  
   function PreviousRecord()
   {
   var record = document.getElementById("record").value;
   var previousRecord = Number(record) - 1;
   if (previousRecord >= 1)
   {
   document.getElementById("record").value = previousRecord;
   loadRecords();
   }
   }
     
   
  </script> 
   
  </head>
  <body>
    First Name: <input type="text" id="firstname" /><br>
    Last Name: <input type="text" id="lastname" /><br>
    Street: <input type="text" id="street" /><br>
    City: <input type="text" id="city" /><br>
    State: <input type="text" id="state" /><br>
    Zip: <input type="text" id="zip" /><br>
    
    <input type="button" value="<" onclick= "PreviousRecord()" />
    <input type="text" value="1" id= "record" size = "2px" />
    <input type="hidden" id="maxRecord" />
    <input type="button" value=">" onclick="NextRecord()" />
    <script> loadRecords();</script> 
    
  </body>
</html>
```

Hi all,

I tried to make a HTML form that can navigate through the records on google spreadsheet. I'm able to get the HTML form on the spreadsheet but the records on the spreadsheet aren't shown on the HTML form. Could you please help tell me what I did wrong. Really appreciated your help.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yIXQ7.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few errors in your javascript code.

1. document.getElementById is the correct usage. you have an upper case 'D' in ID.
2. Less than or equal to only needs one equal sign. '<=' is the correct usage. You can see a list of all the logical operators available with Javascript on [this page](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_comparisons.asp).

In order to easily debug javascript issues, you can open your file in a browser and use the developer tools(F12). If there are any errors, they would be displayed on the console tab with the exact line numbers along with the details of the error.

Comment: Thank you Adarsh for helping scanning the code for me. I also found I typed consule instead of console. What do you mean by opening the file in a browse? How can I save the script into file and open on a browser? This script was saved inside the google spreadsheet.

Comment: if you look at it for the most part it is just a simple html file and would behave like one when opened in a browser. It may not work as expected, but at least syntax errors can be caught easily. You can save everything from the <html> to </html> in a html file and open it in a browser.